# Composer autoload doesn't work successfully and returns undefined variable

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to configure Composer autoload but it seems to work not correctly. PHP doesn't see included variables from other files.

a1.php

```
<?php

echo "Test";
$a = "Hello";
```

a2.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

echo $a;
```

So I it comes to

```
Test
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
```

I can't understand, why it can see "Test" but it can't see my variable $a.
But if I try the same thing without Composer (with include or require), it works well.

Comment: `global $a;` :D

Answer (score 2):

Autoload is for classes only, it does not incluse variables.

You should try using globals, or better : avoid using variables defined in a différent file/scope

Comment: And even with classes it won't do magic. You still need to configure it.

Comment: Yeah, obviously